# SSIS Bulk Insert Task Editor XML File

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

Good Day,

I am attempting to use SSIS to bulk insert XML files into a sql database. Within the Bulk Insert Task editor there are two options beneath the Connection section of the window beneath heading Format, they are "Specify" and "Use File". "Specify" appears to speak to traditional files, and I am thinking this is not applicable to xml files (?). The other option is "Use File", to exercise this option what would I need to do in relation to my source file?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use a DataFlow task with an XML source?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my goal of bulk inserting all xml files from a directory using the following script within a "Execute SQL Task" task. Ensure that within your "Execute SQL Task" that option ByPassPrepare is set to "True". Also on the Parameter Mapping section your parameter name MUST be preceded by an "@" character. You cannot call your variable in your sql by the name you just defined, a question mark must be used. If you are making multiple variable calls in the same script you have to adjust how you are calling the question marks. Within the For Each loop container where the execute sql task resides go to the Collection section, define your folder where the files reside that you want to load (Folder), and define your files (Files)  as *.xml. Within the "Parameter Mapping" section register the user defined variable that contains the file path (Remember must contain an actual file in the variable definition).

declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
INSERT INTO testXMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + ? + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;'

exec(@sql)